# jQuery function not getting called from C# code behind with RegisterStartupScript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a `jQuery` function:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("1");
            function hideInfo() {
                alert("2");
                $("#h3memberInfo").fadeOut("slow");
            };
        });

    </script>
```

I am trying to call above function from c# as below.

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "alert", "hideInfo();", true);
```

On page load I get `alert("1")` but `alert("2")` is never triggered.

What wrong am I doing?

Comment: you are not calling the function anywhere.... although you don't have access to the function outside the scope..... to make it accessible define it in global context or handle click event using jQuery

Comment: when is the c# code get executed?

Comment: Same way I am able to call javascript function. What additional I have to do.!

Comment: @Tal87 - on one of the button click.

Comment: We need more code to diagnose this issue. What happens when you click it? Do you get an error in your console? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: @DKR :  simply define the function in global context

Comment: @FrankerZ. a db call is made on button click after that a label is displayed  for notification and then this function is supposed to fadeout that label.

Comment: @PranavCBalan This is a child page where I am working with jquery.

Comment: @DKR :  move the function definition to outside the document ready handler

Comment: @PranavCBalan. it is called now. But fadeout effect is not working.. the second line of fuction.

Comment: seems like the script is rendered before the page's client onload event is raised. instead of calling the hideInfo,  try writing its content in the registerstartupscript. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @tal87, are you suggesting like this: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "alert", "$("#h3memberInfo").fadeOut("slow");", true);

Comment: @DKR the function is calling before the element is loading..... it's better to handle click event using jQuery

Comment: @PranavCBalan. cant do that, its a dynamic button which makes a db call

Comment: @DKR, please try my modified code below

Comment: @DKR exactly! see example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DKR :  use event delegation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your function `hideInfo()` is wrapped inside the `$(document).ready` block, its not available in the global scope as you try from the code behind.

You can modify your code as below,

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function hideInfo() {    
           $(document).ready(function () {
                alert("1");
                $("#h3memberInfo").fadeOut("slow");                
           });
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: function is called. but 2nd line of funtion to fadeout label is not working.

Comment: Is this the id `#h3memberInfo` correct? Can you check this in the html `view source`? If it's a ASP.Net control id will be changed in the view source.

Comment: on browser, id is childcontainer_h3memberinfo. how do I access clientID in jquery?

Comment: Yes, change the line to `$('#childcontainer_h3memberinfo')` or give a unique css class name and use jquery selector with the class name to the control like, `$('.uniqueClass')`.

Comment: would this ID change in future?

Comment: It won't change unless you change the parent or parent id `childcontainer`

Comment: @DKR, great :-)